# Why does admin get "You don't have permission to edit anything" when running under StaticLiveServerCase but it works okay under the development server

Tags: django-admin, django-testing

Using django 1.7 I have created an admin user who is not a superuser and so can only edit the app models (teachers and work rosters). When running under the development server it works okay; I can log in as andy the admin and I see only the links for editing rosters and teachers. The problem occurs with the test I wrote for this; running under StaticLiveServerCase andy the admin gets the "You don't have permission to edit anything" error.

Here is the test:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from .base import FunctionalTest

class TeacherCreationTest(FunctionalTest):
    fixtures = ['andy_the_admin.json']

    def test_can_create_new_teacher_via_admin(self):
        # Andy, the administrator, opens his web browser, and 
        # goes to the admin page
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')

        # He types in his username and password and hits return
        username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        username_field.send_keys('andy')
        password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        password_field.send_keys('adminpass')
        password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # His username and password are accepted, and he is taken to
        # the Site Administration page
        body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
        self.assertIn('Site administration', body.text)

        # He now sees a hyperlink that says "Teachers"
        teacher_links = self.browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Teachers')
        self.assertTrue(len(teacher_links) > 0)
```

The FunctionalTest class is a subclass of StaticLiveServerCase. It holds the setUp() and tearDown() functions which instantiate a browser and quit it after each test. It fails with the message, self.assertTrue(len(teacher_links) > 0)
AssertionError: False is not true

The fixture, andy_the_admin.json, was created by running dumpdata auth.User > fixtures/andy_the_user.json. I have tried deleting the database (sqlite3) and remaking it afresh before creating the fixture. I have also tried creating the fixture by dumpdata auth.User rosters with some teacher records in the database, and I have tried dumpdata -e contenttypes. None of them worked in the test.

Here is the fixture:

```
[
{
  "fields": {
    "username": "robert",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_superuser": true,
    "is_staff": true,
    "last_login": "2014-05-17T17:17:34.215Z",
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": [],
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$CZPPVO7vdgAd$QCHmwSOCMicbSCZeE7SAIX4fHcbE/PcU0s6V14oymeU=",
    "email": "",
    "date_joined": "2014-05-17T17:16:42.382Z"
  },
  "model": "auth.user",
  "pk": 1
},
{
  "fields": {
    "username": "andy",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_superuser": false,
    "is_staff": true,
    "last_login": "2014-05-17T17:20:18.152Z",
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": [
      19,
      20,
      21
    ],
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$JEECtYmNDGIE$FObcdtu7z+6kRwLBPiRcBcwbGHUN0Xz796Vr7CWYndw=",
    "email": "",
    "date_joined": "2014-05-17T17:18:10Z"
  },`enter code here`
  "model": "auth.user",
  "pk": 2
}
]
```

If I edit the fixture so that andy.is_superuser is True then the test works okay; andy can edit teachers and rosters but he can also edit users and groups, which I do not want. The fact that andy's login works okay under the development server makes it very difficult to think of anything that could be wrong with my project setup. The fact that the test runs correctly if I make andy a superuser makes it difficult to think of anything that could be wrong with the test. A couple of days of Googling has only turned up errors when running under the development server.

Comment: After a long break I came back to this project and upgraded to django 1.8. After making a small edit because StaticLiveServerCase is now StaticLiveServerTestCase the test passed. The problem was never solved, it just went away.